# Update text view after every second based on my current location

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have used google play-services-location for getting the current location and displaying latitude and longitude using function `getLocation()`.

Latitude and longitude are two different `TextView`.

But now I want to update latitude and longitude each second but it has some issue.

I have been trying to use thread class but I am not getting the result.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 public String latitude, longitude;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    requestPermission();

    Thread thread = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            getLocation();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    thread.start();


}

private void requestPermission(){
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
}

public void getLocation(){

    FusedLocationProviderClient
        client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        client.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this,new OnSuccessListener<Location>(){

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {

                        if(location!=null){

                            latitude = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
                            TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.latitude_text);
                            textView.setText( "Latitude :- " + latitude );

                            longitude = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
                            textView = findViewById(R.id.longitude_text);
                            textView.setText("Longitude :- " + longitude );

                        }
                    }
                }
        );

 }
}
```

Comment: do you have tried to debug the code? can you explain where is the error in your snippet? what's error it is?

Comment: Welcome, you said "but it has some issue" but you never mentioned what the issue is. Please try to explain your issue better and we will do our best to help you out

Comment: The code has no errors but my latitude and longitude and not updating every second that is the issue.

Comment: does `onSuccess(Location location)` get called successfully?

Comment: Looks like you don't wait for the `requestPermissions` response (this would be in the acitivitys `onRequestPermissionsResult`) - which would still work in your solution since you keep trying - but do you ever see the permission request prompt?  And it's always worthwhile to log error cases: checkPermissions failure and the thread exception block.  Your thread code looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `postDelayed` method of `Handler` at the end of your `getLocation()` method like this

```
  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getLocation();
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use handler.postDelayed() to run a code every x miliseccends.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed({
    // your code that you want to run
}, 1000//every 1000miliseccond run that code)
```

Answer (score 0):

So For continues location update, you have to request for location update from fused API client:

```
 private void startLocationUpdates() {
        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,
                locationCallback,
                null /* Looper */);
    }
```

---

Create location request object as:

```
 protected void createLocationRequest() {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(10000); // set interval for location update
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }
```

---

Here is my location callback object in onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...

    locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            if (locationResult == null) {
                return;
            }
            for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                // here you will get the locatin object and from locatin object you easily get the latitude and logitude
                // ...
            }
        };
    };
}
```